# One line command in windows to get computer's ip address over my wifi network

Tags: command-line, ip

I have a windows server setup where I would like to get the wifi ip address of server dynamically.

The problem is that ipconfig returns a huge string and the script I am using wants the address straightaway. Is there any command to get this straightaway? I am open to the idea of an external .bat script or a mini CLI software that I can put on my server so that my script talks to that script to get the ip address over wifi network.

Comment: There is no such thing as a wifi address - It might be a ip address, but server's don't generally use wifi. I'm slightly confused to what you *really* need.

Comment: Is powershell a option for the scripting language?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Yes, it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Powershell 2.0 and up:

```
PS C:\Users\User> Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Filter IPENABLED=TRUE | Select IPAddress

IPAddress
---------
{192.168.1.100, ****::****:****:****:****}
```

Note that this will give you all IP addresses on the computer, there's some filtering you could do to isolate just the IPv4 address.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get *some* information from the system to get this to work perfectly. wmic will give you this information if you ask it the right way.

`wmic nicconfig` will give you information on *all* your adaptors, unfortunately with a line ending which notepad can't read. Run `wmic nicconfig > file.txt` and open file.txt in notepad ++ - You need to find a column called "Caption". In my case it reads `[00000000] Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter` - you can use this to search for information on that specific adaptor .

Running  `wmic nicconfig where Caption="[00000000] Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter" get ipaddress` would export the values of the ip addresses or that specific interface in the format `{"192.168.1.137", "fe80::XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX"}`  (I run dual stack). You can simply use something like gnu cut or some other tool to strip the unnecessary characters from the output.

As indicated in the comments, powershell will likely do all this including getting information from wmi and and getting the information out

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the below to fit your needs.

```
@ECHO OFF
::=======================================================================
::  Author: Andrew Tsai
::  Date  : 04-15-2014
::=======================================================================
CLS
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

ECHO Retrieving MAC Addresses
FOR /F "tokens=1 delims= " %%a in ('getmac ^| findstr "\-" ^| findstr /v "00-50-56"')     do (
    SET vMAC=%%a
    SET vMAC=!vMAC:-=:!

    ECHO Retrieving Ethernet Adapter Name for !vMAC!
    %windir%\system32\wbem\wmic.exe /output:NICName.txt nic where MACAddress="!vMAC!"     get NetConnectionID
    for /F "skip=1 tokens=1 delims=" %%l in ('type "NICName.txt"') do (
        SET LAN_NAME=%%l
        REM Trim Trailing Spaces
        for /l %%m in (1,1,31) do if "!LAN_NAME:~-1!"==" " SETLAN_NAME=!LAN_NAME:~0,-1!
     )

    ECHO Retrieving IP
    FOR /F "tokens=2 delims= " %%a IN ('netsh int ipv4 show ipaddresses "!LAN_NAME!" ^| find "Parameters"') DO SET CurIP=%%a
)
FOR /F "tokens=2 delims= " %%a in ('%windir%\system32\nslookup myip.opendns.com resolver1.opendns.com ^| find "Address" ^| find ^/V "208.67.222.222"') DO SET ExtIP=%%a

ECHO.
ECHO Current LAN = !LAN_NAME!
ECHO Current MAC = !vMAC!
ECHO Current Internal IP = !CurIP!
ECHO Current External IP = !ExtIP!
ECHO.
REM SET LAN_NAME
REM SET vMAC
REM SET CurIP
REM SET ExtIP

ENDLOCAL
ENDLOCAL

:END
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ipconfig|grep -m 1 IPv4|sed "s/IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : //g"|sed 's/   //g'|clip
```

This is a .Cmd version that gives only the address your looking for.

GNUWin32, cygwin, and unxutils are 3 packages that will provide the commands "grep" and "sed"